# Tomcat7 .war project not deploying

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, war

I'm trying to deploy a .war project to my tomcat7 installation.

Before copying, I stop the server, copy the war to /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps and then restart the server after it has copied.

When the server starts, the contents are copied out into it's own directory however I get 404 status' when trying to access it from a browser.

Other war files work, and this war file works when used in Eclipse Java EE, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and Tomcat7.

Comment: Check for errors in your tomcat/logs/*.* files, and post error messages if solution not obvious.

Comment: I thought of checking the error logs just after I posted the question.   I receive `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/gridsam-fallback.log (Permission denied)`. Is there anyway I can give the project permissions to access these files?

Comment: Does your application provide a web.xml or does it initialize with a WebInitializer (Servlet API 3)?

Comment: The application provides a web.xml - can I modify it to give it access to the file system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the comments, when you get "permission denied" on temporary files, this IMHO typically shows that you have started tomcat as a different user - commonly this happens when you first start tomcat as root (creating all the temporary files as root) and then as an unprivileged user (who can't overwrite the temporary files).

Technically speaking, when you run as root again, the problems probably disappear, however, this is a security hazard and you should only do this if you want to test the effect. The proper way of doing it is to fix the permissions on temporary files and then **never** run as root again.

A good way to do this (especially if you run as daemon/service) is to have the startup script automatically set the required owner/permissions on temp, work and log directory (maybe more, you'll have to try) and then assert that tomcat is started as that owner. Starting a daemon is typically done as root, so the startup script probably has the correct permissions to do all of this: `chown`, `chmod` and `su` are your friends here.

A very simple tomcat start script in /etc/init.d/tomcat (on ubuntu) looks like this (user: tomcat, location: /opt/tomcat):

```
# Tomcat auto-start
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          tomcat
# Required-Start:    $apache2
# Required-Stop:     $apache2
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# X-Interactive:     true
# Short-Description: Start/stop tomcat server
### END INIT INFO

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
cd /opt/tomcat
chown -R tomcat webapps conf temp logs work

case $1 in
start)
        sudo -u tomcat /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
        ;;
stop)  
        sudo -u tomcat /opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
        ;;
restart)
        sudo -u tomcat /opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
        sudo -u tomcat /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
        ;;
esac   
exit 0
```

with this, I can do `sudo service tomcat restart` (for example) and don't need to pay attention to the proper permissions any more